# MSP430 Syntax: Assembly & C Questions

Tags: assembly, msp430, texas-instruments, code-composer

I am coding an msp430 using the code composer, my questions are below:

--What specific assembly language does it use?

(I am looking for a guide to learn the syntax but cannot find the name of the language.)

--What is a list of addressable components on an embedded system called?

(I see them address components and im not sure where the names come from.)

Comment: it is the msp430 assembly language.  the specific syntax depends on the assembler, the program that converts assembly language into machine code.  wikipedia has a good msp430 instruction set reference I think on the main msp430 page.  normally they are called peripherals.  uart, gpio, etc.  the spi/i2c/uart I think TI lumps into a universal serial interface or some name, names can vary from company to company, not really important, just look at the chip documentation for the device from the ti website.  you can use gnu tools as well dont have to use code composer.

Comment: Have you tried looking at the documentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The assembly language for the MSP430 is called MSP430 Assembly Language, and is documented in the [MSP430 Assembly Language Tools User's Guide](http://www.ti.com/lit/pdf/slau131).

Every chip has its own combination of peripheral modules. There is a family user's guide that describes in detail all modules that chips in a family could have, and a device-specific datasheet that describes which modules a particular chip actually has. For example, the [MSP430G2553 web page](http://www.ti.com/product/msp430g2553) links to the [MSP430x2xx Family User's Guide](http://www.ti.com/lit/pdf/slau144) and the [MSP430G2553 datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/gpn/msp430g2553). Each chip has its own header file (e.g., `<msp430g2553.h>`) that is automatically selected by `<msp430.h>` based on the compiler settings.